# Error: Bound mismatch, Collections.sort, interface, compareTo Method

Tags: java, arraylist, interface

I want to compare a new class called CalendarDate. I made an interface Comparable, and I make the public class CalendarDate implementing Comparable. I also wrote a compareTo(CalendarDate Other) method in the class.

However, when I try *Collections.sort*(birthday), it says Bound mismatch. (It has details: Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList). The inferred type CalendarDate is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter >)

what is wrong with my code? Thanks.

P.S. There is a RED line under the word *sort* in CalendarDateTest.java.

Comparable.java

```
package Chapter10;

public interface Comparable<T> {
    public int compareTo(T other);
}
```

CalendarDate.java

```
package Chapter10;

public class CalendarDate implements Comparable<CalendarDate> {
    private int month;
    private int day;

    public CalendarDate(int month, int day) {
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
    }

    public int compareTo(CalendarDate other) {
        if (month != other.month) {
            return month - other.month;
        }
        else {
            return day - other.day;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return month + "/" + day;
    }
}
```

CalendarDateTest.java

```
package Chapter10;

import java.util.*;

public class CalendarDateTest {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ArrayList<CalendarDate> birthday = new ArrayList<CalendarDate>();
        birthday.add(new CalendarDate(1, 23));
        birthday.add(new CalendarDate(5, 18));
        birthday.add(new CalendarDate(12, 17));
        birthday.add(new CalendarDate(2, 29));
        birthday.add(new CalendarDate(8, 6));

        System.out.println("birthdays = " + birthday);
        Collections.sort(birthday);
        System.out.println("birthdays = " + birthday);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have re-defined the [`Comparable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface that Java has already defined. As far as Java is concerned, these are two entirely different, unrelated interfaces, despite having the same name. The `Collections.sort` method knows about `java.lang.Comparable<T>`, but it has no idea about your `Chapter10.Comparable<T>`.

Remove Comparable.java file from your project, recompile, and run; this should fix the problem.

[Running demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/OW6wjD)

Comment: Thx so much for the explanation & the solution. it works! thx also for the efficient reply.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `java.lang.Comparable<T>` interface instead of your own implementation.

If you still like to use your own interface with extended functionality your interface must extend the `java.lang.Comparable<T>` interface. But note that for using it with the `Collections.sort()` method this makes no difference.

**Tip:** To be sure you override an existing method you should add an `@Override` annotation to `compareTo()` and `toString()`.